# How to Fetch database table value to frontend

Tags: magento2

I have a custom module that checks Pincode, kindly check the screenshots below:-
[image]

I have created a custom import function and added a table to the database which will hold the value imported by CSV below is the screenshot:-

[image]

now I want to fetch this table on the frontend where I check Pincode and if the Pincode exist in the database then it should show the message of delivery available.

please also check the code below

**vendor/module/Model/Pincode.php**

```
<?php
namespace Learn\CheckDelivery\Model;

class Pincode extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Learn\CheckDelivery\Model\ResourceModel\Pincode');
    }
}
```

**vendor/module/Model/ResourceModel/Pincode.php**

```
<?php
namespace Learn\CheckDelivery\Model\ResourceModel;

class Pincode extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('learn_checkdelivery', 'id');
    }
}
```

**vendor/module/Model/ResourceModel/Pincode/Collection.php**

```
<?php
namespace Learn\CheckDelivery\Model\ResourceModel\Pincode;

class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection 
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Learn\CheckDelivery\Model\Pincode','Learn\CheckDelivery\Model\ResourceModel\Pincode');
    }

    //print_r($datacollection);
}
```

now I want to know how to achieve this

**UPDATE**

**VENDOR/MODULE/view/frontend/layout/templates/product/view/check_delivery.phtml**

```
<?php $product = $this->getCurrentProduct()  ?>

<?php $helper=$this->helper("Learn\CheckDelivery\Helper\Data");?>
<?php if($product && $product->getCheckDeliveryEnable() != 2 && $helper->getIsActive() == 1): ?>
    <form class="form" id="check-delivery-form" method="post">
       <fieldset class="fieldset">
           <legend class="legend"><span><?php echo __('Check Delivery') ?></span></legend><br>
            <div class="field required">
                <label for="delivery_postcode" class="label"><span><?php echo __('Postcode') ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="text" name="postcode" id="delivery_postcode" value="" title="<?php echo __('Postcode') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-digits':true}">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="message"></div>
       </fieldset>
       <div class="actions-toolbar">
            <div class="primary">
                <button type="submit" class="action submit primary action-check-delivery" title="<?php  echo __('Check') ?>"><span><?php echo __('Check') ?></span></button>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </form>

<script>
require([
    'jquery',
    'mage/mage'
], function ($) { 
    var dataForm = $('#check-delivery-form');
    dataForm.mage('validation', {});
    var dataFormMessage = $('#check-delivery-form .message');
    dataFormMessage.removeClass('success').removeClass('error').hide();
    $('.action-check-delivery').on('click',function () {
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('postcode', $('#check-delivery-form input[name="postcode"]').val());
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkDelivery/postcode/check',['id'=> $product->getId()]) ?>',
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                showLoader: true,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    dataFormMessage.removeClass('success').removeClass('error').hide();
                    dataFormMessage.addClass(response.type).html(response.message).show();
                }
            });
            return false;
    });
});
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Block.php**

```
<?php

namespace Learn\CheckDelivery\Block\Product\View;

use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;

class CheckDelivery extends Template
{

    protected $_registry;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_registry = $registry;
    }



    public function getCurrentProduct()
    {
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
    }
}
```

Comment: check my answer here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/303727/how-to-fetch-data-from-a-custom-table-in-magento2-and-show-in-home-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@pramod

you can simply get the collection of your model like : 
this code you need to write down in your block file.

```
<?php

namespace Learn\CheckDelivery\Block\Product\View;

use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;

class CheckDelivery extends Template
{

    protected $_registry;
    protected $_$pincode;
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Registry $registry,
        \Learn\CheckDelivery\Model\PincodeFactory $pincode,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        $this->_pincode = $pincode;
    }

    public function getPincodeCollection($pincode){
      $collection = $this->_pincode->create();
$collection->getCollection();
$collection->addFiledtoFilter('pincode',$pincode);
$collection->getData();
//you can check the data here like
return $collection;
    }

    public function getCurrentProduct()
    {
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
    }
}
```

in your phtml :

```
<script>
require([
    'jquery',
    'mage/mage'
], function ($) { 
    var dataForm = $('#check-delivery-form');
    dataForm.mage('validation', {});
    var dataFormMessage = $('#check-delivery-form .message');
    dataFormMessage.removeClass('success').removeClass('error').hide();
    $('.action-check-delivery').on('click',function () {
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('postcode', $('#check-delivery-form input[name="postcode"]').val());
            var pincode = $('#check-delivery-form input[name="postcode"]').val(); 
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkDelivery/postcode/check',['postcode'=> pincode]) ?>',
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                showLoader: true,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    dataFormMessage.removeClass('success').removeClass('error').hide();
                    dataFormMessage.addClass(response.type).html(response.message).show();
                }
            });
            return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: i think there is problem in phtml file as after using your code pincode check field does not show up

Comment: url: '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkDelivery/postcode/check',['postcode'=> pincode]) ?>',  i think there is an issue with line

Comment: you need to check that in var pincode you have to got a proper value or not ? if you got a proper value then i must a pass in ajax data

Comment: or as per your phtml code                     <input type="text" name="postcode" id="delivery_postcode" value="" title="<?php echo __('Postcode') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-digits':true}">   you need to set var pincode = $('#delivery_postcode').val(); i hope so this will work for you

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the model collection factory into your constructor

```
protected $yourCollectionFactory;
public function __construct(
    ....
    \[Namespace]\[Module]\Model\ResourceModel\[Entity]\CollectionFactory $yourCollectionFactory,
    ...
)
{
    ...
    $this->yourCollectionFactory = $yourCollectionFactory;
    ...
}
```

And use in your method like the below example.

```
public function yourMethod(){
    $collection = $this->yourCollectionFactory->create();
}
```

I hope it'll help you.

Comment: am not gettting it. i want to get the collection my phtml file where this check delivery form is coming up

Comment: @Pramod First you need to get the collection on your block files method and then call that method on your .phtml file.

Comment: do you want me to share my block code also?/

Comment: @Pramod Yes, I'll would be good if you  share your block code with us.

Comment: sure give me a min sir

Comment: sir please check my updated question, thanks

Comment: I have checked your .phtml code which you have shared now. I think you need to call your model collection on your controller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104251/discussion-between-mayank-zalavadia-and-pramod).