# How to fetch data from a custom table in magento2 and show in home page

Tags: magento2, module, database, custom

I have created a custom module with a custom table, now I need to fetch the data from the table and display in the home page. I achieved it by applying object manager I know it's not the correct method can anyone please tell me how to do it.

thank you

Comment: create model....

Comment: created model and resource model also collection

Comment: you can easily get table data using model

Comment: can u help me in getting I am new to magento2 .

Comment: check my answer

Comment: please check my updated answer and update me.

Answer (score 3):

1) I Assume you have created Model and Collection file associated with that tables.

2) In a Block PHP file constructor add one argument (Dependency Injection) like below and store it in a class member variable.

```
 public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    \Namespace\Modulename\Model\ModelNameFactory $modelNameFactory,

    array $data = array()
) {
    $this->_modelFactory = $modelFactory;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}
```

3) Prepare a public method in your block to access collection like below.

```
public function getCollection(){

    return $this->_modelFactory->create()->getCollection();

}
```

4) Loop through each of the collection result.

Comment: I am a newbie so please help in doing the task

Answer (score 1):

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Setup**

***InstallSchema.php***

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();
        $table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable(
            $installer->getTable('custom_table_name')
        )->addColumn(
            'id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            ['identity' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
            'Id'
        )->addColumn(
            'prd_entity_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            ['nullable' => false],
            'Product Entity ID'
        )->addColumn(
            'prd_sku',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            ['nullable' => false],
            'Product SKU'
        )->addColumn(
            'usr_name',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            ['nullable' => false],
            'User Name'
        )->addColumn(
            'email',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            ['nullable' => false],
            'Email Address'
        )->addColumn(
            'subject',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            '2M',
            ['nullable' => false],
            'Subject'
        )->addColumn(
            'msg',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            '2M',
            ['nullable' => false],
            'Massage'
        )->addColumn(
            'pubish_datetime',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
            null,
            [
                'nullable' => false,
                'default' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT,
            ],
            'Publish Date Time'
        )->addColumn(
            'update_datetime',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
            null,
            [],
            'Modification Date Time'
        )->setComment(
            'Custome Table'
        );
        $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

here column name are my you can put your column name

Now create an Modal

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Model**

***Customtable.php***

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Model;

use VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\Customtable as CustomtableResourceModel;

class Customtable extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{
    const CACHE_TAG = 'custom_table_name';

    protected $_cacheTag = 'custom_table_name';
    protected $_eventPrefix = 'custom_table_name';

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(CustomtableResourceModel::class);
    }

}
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Model/ResourceModel**

***Customtable.php***

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel;

class Customtable extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
{
    protected $_idFieldName = 'id';
    protected $_date;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $date,
        $resourcePrefix = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $resourcePrefix);
        $this->_date = $date;
    }
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('custom_table_name', 'id');
    }
}
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Model/ResourceModel/Customtable**

***Collection.php***

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\Customtable;

use VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\Customtable as CustomtableModel;
use VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\Customtable as CustomtableResourceModel;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    protected $_idFieldName = 'id';

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(
            CustomtableModel::class,
            CustomtableResourceModel::class
        );
    }
}
```

crate an block file

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Block**

***CustomeBlock.php***

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Block;

use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;

class CustomeBlock extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $customData;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\Customtable\CollectionFactory $customData
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->customData = $customData;
    }
    public function getCustomTableData()
    {
        return $this->customData->create();
    }
}
```

add this into phtml file

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/frontend/templates**

***customefile.phtml***

```
<?php

print_r($block->getCustomTableData()->getData());

?>
<h1> Call phtml file</h1>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout**

***cms_index_index.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\CustomeBlock" template="VendoreName_ModuleName::customefile.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

after that run magento command

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d
php bin/magento c:c
```

Note: please check your custome table in database and also check your Module name in **setup_module** table.