# I want to display my custom module table data in front page (Magento 2)

Tags: module, custom

```
<?php

namespace WebQillaModule\FinalModule\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{  
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();


        $setup->getConnection()
            ->addColumn(
                $setup->getTable('first_table'),
                'Date',
                 \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_DATE,
                null,
                'Post Date'
            );

        $setup->getConnection()
            ->addColumn(
                $setup->getTable('first_table'),
                'Logo',
                 \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                null,
                'Post Logo'
        );

        $setup->endSetup();

    }
}
```

I added these new 2 new fields in my table first table how to show these in front end page of this custom module

[image: front page showing only title and content of blog post of my custom module]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Your **UpgradeSchema.php** is wrong. please check here.

```
<?php

namespace WebQillaModule\FinalModule\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
        $tableName = $setup->getTable('first_table');
        // you must check you module version in module.xml (must be same)
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1', '<')) {
            $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
                $setup->getTable($tableName),
                'logo',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    'nullable' => false,
                    'comment' => 'Post Logo',
                ]
            );
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

> And you **module.xml** file in **app/code/WebQillaModule/FinalModule/etc** has same vesion name like below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="WebQillaModule_FinalModule" setup_version="1.0.1">
    </module>
</config>
```

> After save both file run this command

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d
php bin/magento c:c
```

> You can check version is update or not in **setup_module** table. and also check this column is added in you table or not. and you can get this column value like other like other column value.
>
> **Update**
>
> create an Modal

**app/code/WebQillaModule/FinalModule/Model**

***Customtable.php***

```
<?php

namespace WebQillaModule\FinalModule\Model;

use WebQillaModule\FinalModule\Model\ResourceModel\Customtable as CustomtableResourceModel;

class Customtable extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{
    const CACHE_TAG = 'first_table';

    protected $_cacheTag = 'first_table';
    protected $_eventPrefix = 'first_table';

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(CustomtableResourceModel::class);
    }

}
```

**app/code/WebQillaModule/FinalModule/Model/ResourceModel**

***Customtable.php***

```
<?php

namespace WebQillaModule\FinalModule\Model\ResourceModel;

class Customtable extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
{
    protected $_idFieldName = 'id';
    protected $_date;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $date,
        $resourcePrefix = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $resourcePrefix);
        $this->_date = $date;
    }
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('first_table', 'id'); // add here your primary key column name
    }
}
```

**app/code/WebQillaModule/FinalModule/Model/ResourceModel/Customtable**

***Collection.php***

```
<?php

namespace WebQillaModule\FinalModule\Model\ResourceModel\Customtable;

use WebQillaModule\FinalModule\Model\Customtable as CustomtableModel;
use WebQillaModule\FinalModule\Model\ResourceModel\Customtable as CustomtableResourceModel;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    protected $_idFieldName = 'id';

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(
            CustomtableModel::class,
            CustomtableResourceModel::class
        );
    }
}
```

create controller file

**app/code/WebQillaModule/FinalModule/Controller/Index**

***Index.php***

```
<?php

namespace WebQillaModule\FinalModule\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function execute()
    {

        return $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

crate an block file

**app/code/WebQillaModule/FinalModule/Block**

***CustomeBlock.php***

```
<?php

namespace WebQillaModule\FinalModule\Block;

use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;

class CustomeBlock extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $customData;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \WebQillaModule\FinalModule\Model\CustomtableFactory $customData
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->customData = $customData;
    }
    public function getCustomTableData()
    {
        return $this->customData->create();
    }
}
```

add this into phtml file

**app/code/WebQillaModule/FinalModule/view/frontend/templates**

***customefile.phtml***

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
print_r($block->getCustomTableData()->getData());
echo "</pre>";
?>
<h1> Call phtml file</h1>
```

**app/code/WebQillaModule/FinalModule/view/frontend/layout**

***tempfront_index_index.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="WebQillaModule\FinalModule\Block\CustomeBlock" template="WebQillaModule_FinalModule::customefile.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

after that run magento command

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d
php bin/magento c:c
```

Note: please check your custome table in database and also check your Module name in **setup_module** table.

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: for display your data check this link  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/303727/how-to-fetch-data-from-a-custom-table-in-magento2-and-show-in-home-page/303748#303748

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply but this is not what i was asking you i have done this code and got table output correctly title,content, date and image is saving in database table i just want to show this fields (date and image) in frontend too like title and content

Comment: Check my Updated answer and update me.

Comment: I want to clear one thing i have a model and controller for title and content do i need to create separate model and controller for showing new fields? and please see my above updated question too

Comment: Can I know about what you want to do.you can call data sa your requirement.

Comment: nothing nothing your code worked for me thank you so much

Comment: If it's work for you so please accept and vote up . Which helps to other people to find best solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can call your table data on frontend, you can add below code on block and call block function in template.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
    \Vendor\Modulename\Model\ModelnameFactory $modelnameFactory,        
    array $data = []
)
{    
    $this->modelnameFactory= $modelnameFactory;    
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

 public function getCollection()
{
    $collection = $this->modelnameFactory->create()->getCollection();
    return $collection;
}
```

You need to add below code to your template

```
$collection = $block->getCollection();
```

Comment: when you say block, are you talking about the vendor\module\Block\Adminhtml ?