# Magento 2 get collection custom module

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I made a module, following a tutorial, but now I need to call these items registered in the module, to my store home

my module is Create / Save Admin Grid

how do i call these saved lines on my module?

this is my module structure, it works correctly, but I can't call it in a .phtml file

[image]

can anybody help me? I've been looking for the solution for days, but I'm not able to call the store home

my block
app/code/Zeepi/ZeepiConfiguracoes/Block/Adminhtml/Banner.php

```
<?php

namespace Zeepi\ZeepiConfiguracoes\Block\Adminhtml;

class Banner extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Container
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_template = 'banner/banner.phtml';

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context,        
    \Zeepi\ZeepiConfiguracoes\Model\BannerFactory $modelnameFactory,
    array $data = [])
    {
        $this->BannerFactory= $modelnameFactory;    
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }


    /**
     * Prepare button and grid
     *
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product
     */
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {


        $addButtonProps = [
            'id' => 'add_new',
            'label' => __('Add New'),
            'class' => 'add',
            'button_class' => '',
            'class_name' => 'Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button\SplitButton',
            'options' => $this->_getAddButtonOptions(),
        ];
        $this->buttonList->add('add_new', $addButtonProps);


        $this->setChild(
            'grid',
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Zeepi\ZeepiConfiguracoes\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Grid', 'zeepi.banner.grid')
        );
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    /**
     *
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function _getAddButtonOptions()
    {

        $splitButtonOptions[] = [
            'label' => __('Add New'),
            'onclick' => "setLocation('" . $this->_getCreateUrl() . "')"
        ];

        return $splitButtonOptions;
    }

    /**
     *
     *
     * @param string $type
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getCreateUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl(
            'zeepiconfiguracoes/*/new'
        );
    }

    /**
     * Render grid
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGridHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('grid');
    }

    public function getCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->BannerFactory->create()->getCollection();
        return $collection;
    }

}
```

Comment: Try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/309539/i-want-to-display-my-custom-module-table-data-in-front-page-magento-2/309556#309556

Comment: i follow this step, but not work

Comment: try this also https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/303727/how-to-fetch-data-from-a-custom-table-in-magento2-and-show-in-home-page/303748#303748

Comment: where you want to show your data fronted or admin panel ?

Comment: I'm created Magento 2 tutorials channel please Like and Support https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC2JghzAPB7wNBDY0u-OtAig/videos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Create an Modal

**app/code/Zeepi/ZeepiConfiguracoes/Model**

***Bannerdata.php***

```
<?php

namespace Zeepi\ZeepiConfiguracoes\Model;

use Zeepi\ZeepiConfiguracoes\Model\ResourceModel\Bannerdata as BannerdataResourceModel;

class Bannerdata extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{
    const CACHE_TAG = 'custom_table_name';

    protected $_cacheTag = 'custom_table_name';
    protected $_eventPrefix = 'custom_table_name';

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(BannerdataResourceModel::class);
    }

}
```

**app/code/Zeepi/ZeepiConfiguracoes/Model/ResourceModel**

***Bannerdata.php***

```
<?php

namespace Zeepi\ZeepiConfiguracoes\Model\ResourceModel;

class Bannerdata extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
{
    protected $_idFieldName = 'id';
    protected $_date;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $date,
        $resourcePrefix = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $resourcePrefix);
        $this->_date = $date;
    }
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('custom_table_name', 'id'); // add here your tabel name and your primary key column name 
    }
}
```

**app/code/Zeepi/ZeepiConfiguracoes/Model/ResourceModel/Bannerdata**

***Collection.php***

```
<?php

namespace Zeepi\ZeepiConfiguracoes\Model\ResourceModel\Bannerdata;

use Zeepi\ZeepiConfiguracoes\Model\Bannerdata as BannerdataModel;
use Zeepi\ZeepiConfiguracoes\Model\ResourceModel\Bannerdata as BannerdataResourceModel;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    protected $_idFieldName = 'id';

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(
            BannerdataModel::class,
            BannerdataResourceModel::class
        );
    }
}
```

crate an block file

**app/code/Zeepi/ZeepiConfiguracoes/Block**

***CustomeBlock.php***

```
<?php

namespace Zeepi\ZeepiConfiguracoes\Block;

use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;

class CustomeBlock extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $customData;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Zeepi\ZeepiConfiguracoes\Model\ResourceModel\Bannerdata\CollectionFactory $customData
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->customData = $customData;
    }
    public function getCustomTableData()
    {
        return $this->customData->create();
    }
}
```

add this into phtml file

**app/code/Zeepi/ZeepiConfiguracoes/view/frontend/templates**

***banner.phtml***

```
<?php

print_r($block->getCustomTableData()->getData());

?>
<h1> Call phtml file</h1>
```

**app/code/Zeepi/ZeepiConfiguracoes/view/frontend/layout**

***cms_index_index.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Zeepi\ZeepiConfiguracoes\Block\CustomeBlock" template="Zeepi_ZeepiConfiguracoes::banner.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> After that run magento command

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d
php bin/magento c:c
```

> Check you store home page.

Note: please check your custome table in database and also check your Module name in **setup_module** table.

Comment: Please check and update me.

Answer (score 0):

use ResourceModel instead of Model for collection as below

```
\Zeepi\ZeepiConfiguracoes\Model\ResourceModel\Banner\CollectionFactory
```

and call it like

```
$collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
                ->addFieldToFilter('field_id','value');
```

Comment: srry about my ignorance, in my collection.php i have this  protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Zeepi\ZeepiConfiguracoes\Model\Banner', 'Zeepi\ZeepiConfiguracoes\Model\ResourceModel\Banner');
        $this->_map['fields']['page_id'] = 'main_table.page_id';
    }